# Realm Integer crashes project

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to add integer values to my app, but the app just crashes.

This is the Object class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var exersice: String?
    @objc dynamic var sets = 0
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg = 0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?

}
```

And this is how I write it

```
    let currenDate = Date()

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var myWorkout = Workout()
    myWorkout.date = currenDate
    myWorkout.exersice = "Squat"
    myWorkout.sets = 3
    myWorkout.reps = 6
    myWorkout.kg = 70
    myWorkout.notes = "test note"

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(myWorkout)
    }
```

Any ideas? I have followed the exact documentation: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#getting-started

EDIT: This is what happens when I run the project:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F85d.png)

And if I press the `10 ViewController.viewDidLoad()` on the left side, is shows me this: [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfPvb.png)

Comment: What do you mean `crashes`? Any error message?

Comment: @Magnas Updated question with images now.

Comment: Please change exersice to exercise.

Answer (score 1):

For the future: try! means "I'm hundred percent sure there will be no exception, please crash if there is one". Which your code then did. Better use try / catch so you can see which exception gets thrown. It is very, very rare that try! is correct.

Comment: How do I use the try / catch in this case? Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your **Workout** model, thats why realm is throwing Migration is required errors.

Try to remove your app and install again from device / simulator or learn how to migrate in realm.

Answer (score 0):

**Migration error.**

Most of these can be solved simply my updating **schemaVersion**.

**Realm** will know your modal has changed, and solve basic issues for you.

If your modal changes were more complex and have to support backward compatibility, you would have to explain to **realm** how to migrate.

A simple way to do this would be to use your own getRealm, instead of default shared instance:

```
func getRealm() -> Realm {
  var config = Realm.Configuration(
      // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
      // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
      schemaVersion: 2, // This is the number you should update!

      // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
      // a schema version lower than the one set above
      migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
          // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
          if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
              // Nothing to do!
              // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
              // And will update the schema on disk automatically
          }
  })

  do {
      return try Realm.init(configuration: config)
  } catch {
      return try! Realm.init(configuration: config)
  }
}
```

*Easy migration explained:* 
https://medium.com/@shenghuawu/realm-lightweight-migration-4559b9920487